# Use of Boost.Coroutine with Boost.ASIO causes assertion

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, boost-coroutine

I have boost::asio::io_context which is running in several threads (via ctx.run()) and I have several asynchronous objects that are used inside boost.coroutines, which are running via boost::asio::spawn. And I have the following assertion:

```
Assertion failed: ! is_running(), file C:\boost\boost_1_68_0\msvc_x86\include\boost-1_68\boost\coroutine\detail\push_coroutine_impl.hpp, line 258
```

I'm providing a minimal example which causes the same error. Please, help me: what am I doing wrong?

Boost version is 1.68

[Update]: there is a fix in the code (forget to lock io_context), but it doesn't affect assertion anyway.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/spawn.hpp>

template<class CompletionToken>
BOOST_ASIO_INITFN_RESULT_TYPE(CompletionToken, void(boost::system::error_code))
asyncDo(boost::asio::io_context& ctx, CompletionToken&& token)
{
    using CompletionType = boost::asio::async_completion<CompletionToken, void(boost::system::error_code)>;
    CompletionType completion{ token };
    ctx.post(
        [handler{ completion.completion_handler }](){
            using boost::asio::asio_handler_invoke;
            asio_handler_invoke(std::bind(handler, boost::system::error_code()), &handler);
            return;
        });
    return completion.result.get();
}

void coroFunc(boost::asio::io_context& ctx, boost::asio::yield_context yield)
{
    for (;;) {
        std::cerr << std::this_thread::get_id() << '\n';
        asyncDo(ctx, yield);
        std::cerr << std::this_thread::get_id() << '\n';
    }
}

int main(int, char* [])
{
    boost::asio::io_context ctx;
    boost::asio::executor_work_guard<boost::asio::io_context::executor_type> work(ctx.get_executor());

    boost::asio::spawn(ctx, std::bind(coroFunc, std::ref(ctx), std::placeholders::_1));

    std::thread([&ctx]() { ctx.run(); }).detach();
    std::thread([&ctx]() { ctx.run(); }).detach();

    std::cin.get();
    work.reset();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After several hours of googling and trying I've got the solution that works for me (at least at my tests). The main idea is to replace posting to **ctx** with posting to **associated executor**:

```cpp
    auto executor = boost::asio::get_associated_executor(completion.completion_handler, ctx);
    auto allocator = boost::asio::get_associated_allocator(completion.completion_handler);

    executor.post(
        [handler = HandlerType{ std::move(completion.completion_handler) }](){
            using boost::asio::asio_handler_invoke;
            asio_handler_invoke(std::bind(handler, boost::system::error_code()), &handler);
            return;
        },
        allocator);
```

Whole code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <thread>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/spawn.hpp>


template<class CompletionToken>
BOOST_ASIO_INITFN_RESULT_TYPE(CompletionToken, void(boost::system::error_code))
asyncDo(boost::asio::io_context& ctx, CompletionToken&& token)
{
    using CompletionType = boost::asio::async_completion<CompletionToken, void(boost::system::error_code)>;
    using HandlerType = typename CompletionType::completion_handler_type;
    CompletionType completion{ token };

    auto executor = boost::asio::get_associated_executor(completion.completion_handler, ctx);
    auto allocator = boost::asio::get_associated_allocator(completion.completion_handler);

    executor.post(
        [handler = HandlerType{ std::move(completion.completion_handler) }](){
            using boost::asio::asio_handler_invoke;
            asio_handler_invoke(std::bind(handler, boost::system::error_code()), &handler);
            return;
        },
        allocator);

    return completion.result.get();
}

void coroFunc(boost::asio::io_context& ctx, boost::asio::yield_context yield)
{
    for (;;) {
        try {
            std::cerr << "(0): " << std::this_thread::get_id() << '\n';
            asyncDo(ctx, yield);
            std::cerr << "(1): " << std::this_thread::get_id() << '\n';
        } catch (std::exception const& e) {
            std::cerr << "e: " << e.what() << '\n';
        }
    }
}

int main(int, char* [])
{
    boost::asio::io_context ctx;
    boost::asio::executor_work_guard<boost::asio::io_context::executor_type> work(ctx.get_executor());

    boost::asio::spawn(ctx, std::bind(coroFunc, std::ref(ctx), std::placeholders::_1));

    std::thread([&ctx]() {
        for (;;) {
            try {
                ctx.run();
                break;
            } catch (std::exception const& e) {
                std::cerr << "e: " << e.what() << '\n';
            }
        }
    }).detach();
    std::thread([&ctx]() {
        for (;;) {
            try {
                ctx.run();
                break;
            } catch (std::exception const& e) {
                std::cerr << "e: " << e.what() << '\n';
            }
        }
    }).detach();

    std::cin.get();
    work.reset();

    return 0;
}
```